# onclick and checked use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

```
<input type="radio" name="haspayperiod" id="haspayperiod_1" value="0" checked onclick="annualtype_change(this.value);" <?= ($fundcode!="F02001") ? "style='display:none;'" : "" ?> />
```

Like above, I'm using checked and `onclick` to call `annualtype_change(this.value)` in default stage

my annualtype_change function is like below.

```
function annualtype_change(year) {
            $('#regular_TN').hide();
            $('#regular_TN_1').show();

            if (year == "1") {
                $('#regular_TN_1').hide();
                $('#regular_TN_2').show();

            } else {
                $('#regular_TN_1').show();
                $('#regular_TN_2').hide(); //default
            }


        }
```

However, though it appears as checked box, it doesn't show regular_TN_1 by default

```
    <td id="regular_TN_1" >
      <span class="fixprice" name="price" id="price_1"value=20,000>20,000</span>dollar
   </td>
    <td id="regular_TN_2" style="display:none" >
      <span class="fixprice" name="price" id="price_2" value=10,000>10,000</span>dollar
   </td>
```

how should I use `checked` and `onclick` to work correctly.

Comment: just think fundcode as F02001

Comment: I think you are intending to use `checkbox` instead of `radio` button. Check this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/pzq06w72/1/)**

Comment: how about radio? I personally prefer rounded radio tag instead of checkbox

Comment: using radio tag you have check or uncheck it manually to visualize the change! like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/pzq06w72/2/)**

Comment: but there's no difference for radio and check in case of my code. When I just try to open my test web page, though it is checked on radio, it does not display following things

Comment: to keep it on page load you need write it in `$(document).ready(function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the tag name and tag id, which should be carefully adjusted when you fix the code.